# SignIn callback error when using NextAuth with oauth_get_access_token_error and oauth_callback_error

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth, next.js, next-auth

I am trying to add custom oauth provider to my next.js app. I am adding custom provider in `[...nextauth].js`:

```
export default NextAuth({
  // Configure one or more authentication providers
  providers: [
  {
    id: "moneybutton",
    name: "Money Button",
    type: "oauth",
    version: "2.0",
    scope: "auth.user_identity:read users.profiles:read users.profiles.email:read users.balance:read",
    params: {
      grant_type: "authorization_code"
    },
    accessTokenUrl: "https://www.moneybutton.com/oauth/v1/token",
    requestTokenUrl: "https://www.moneybutton.com/oauth/v1/token",
    authorizationUrl: "https://www.moneybutton.com/oauth/v1/authorize?response_type=code",
    profileUrl: "https://www.moneybutton.com/api/v1/auth/user_identity",

    profile(profile) {
      return {
        id: profile.data.attributes.id,
        name: profile.data.attributes.name,
      };
    },
    clientId: 'my_oauth_identifier',
    clientSecret: 'my_client_secret'
  }
    // ...add more providers here
  ],

  debug: true
});
```

OAuth flow seems to work correct, as i am seeing my profile id coming back in responses but it finishes on `http://localhost:3000/api/auth/signin?error=Callback`

I set debug to true and i am getting following errors:

```
[next-auth][error][oauth_get_access_token_error]
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#oauth_get_access_token_error {
  statusCode: 400,
  data: '{"errors":[{"id":"6da534f0-a512-11eb-92e8-891975d02f44","status":400,"title":"Bad Request","detail":"Invalid client: client is invalid"}],"jsonapi":{"version":"1.0"}}'
} undefined undefined
[next-auth][error][oauth_get_access_token_error]
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#oauth_get_access_token_error {
  statusCode: 400,
  data: '{"errors":[{"id":"6da534f0-a512-11eb-92e8-891975d02f44","status":400,"title":"Bad Request","detail":"Invalid client: client is invalid"}],"jsonapi":{"version":"1.0"}}'
} moneybutton 9f3970b8ae39f9d46f9fae56f6fb6135ecb7e87b
[next-auth][error][oauth_callback_error]
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#oauth_callback_error {
  statusCode: 400,
  data: '{"errors":[{"id":"6da534f0-a512-11eb-92e8-891975d02f44","status":400,"title":"Bad Request","detail":"Invalid client: client is invalid"}],"jsonapi":{"version":"1.0"}}'
```

It says that client is invalid, but i am sure oauth identifier and secret are correct, as well as redirect URL set to `http://localhost:3000/api/auth/callback/moneybutton`.

response for profile looks like this if it would be helpful:

```
{
    "data": {
        "id": "75101",
        "type": "user_identities",
        "attributes": {
            "id": "75101",
            "name": "John Doe"
        }
    },
    "jsonapi": {
        "version": "1.0"
    }
}
```

Links to documentations:

- https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/providers
- https://docs.moneybutton.com/docs/api/v1/api-v1-user-identity

I don't know if it's some bug or my approach is wrong and will apreciate any help

Comment: have you resolved the issue?